# Ubuntu 16.04 withh Kernel 4.7 and Broadcom Wireless - no bcmwl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, broadcom

I have manually installed Kernel 4.7 on *buntu 16.04. My WLAN (Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n) uses bcma and wl modules. Tried to add broadcom-sta-dkms via

```
apt install --reinstall
```

which detects Kernel 4.7 but reports:

> Building initial module for 4.7.0-040700-generic
>   ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.7.0-040700-generic is not supported
>   Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.7.0-040700-generic (x86_64)

Anyone a solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might have more luck asking this on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), the Ubuntu-flavor of SE. This seems to be more of an Ubuntu than a programming question.

Comment: moved to askubuntu. Thx !